# Proper way to return a boolean from a Firebase Cloud Function while still returning a Promise?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So Firebase Cloud Functions must all ultimately return promises. If we're dealing with a callable function and the client wishes to obtain a boolean from that function, do we simply return a promise resolved with that boolean or can we just return that boolean?

```
exports.doesUserExistAtPhoneNumber = onCall(async (request) => {
    const phoneNumber = request.data.phoneNumber;

    try {
        const db = getFirestore();
        const snapshot = await db.collection("userAccounts").where("phoneNumber", "==", phoneNumber).get();

        if (snapshot.empty) {
            // There is NO EXISTING user at this phone number.
            return Promise.resolve(false);
        } else {
            // There is INDEED AN EXISTING user at this phone number.
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new HttpsError("unknown", error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, all async functions return a promise.  There are no exceptions to that rule.  From [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description) (emphasis mine):

> An async function declaration creates an AsyncFunction object. Each time when an async function is called, **it returns a new Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function**, or rejected with an exception uncaught within the async function.

Whether or not you explicitly return a promise isn't an issue.  The final return value will be implicitly wrapped in a promise (if not already a promise) in order to satisfy the rule.

So, in an async function, these bits of code have the exact same effect:

1. `return true`
2. `return Promise.resolve(true)`

The primary thing that you, the developer, must do in your code is to make sure that all promises are either awaited or returned as part of its execution.  There are eslint rules to help you track this.  Failure to do so might result is unexpected behavior as Cloud Functions shuts down when the final promise is delivered.

Comment: Is there one or two eslint rules in particular that you recommend using for this?

Comment: I use all of the recommended rules. That should be included in the set.

Comment: And in the case of an async function that doesn't need to return anything of value, simply returning `null` would suffice as even null would be wrapped in a Promise, correct?

Comment: You have no obligation to return anything at all (unless you are using TypeScript perhaps, or some lint rule that demands a return value).  The default return value is `undefined`.  Keep in mind that for callables, the client is going to receive a JSON serialization of what you return.

Comment: So just by declaring the function `async`, one can explicitly return nothing and the function will on its own return a promise with undefined as its associated value?

Comment: That's the expected behavior. Though you might not have much luck with Firebase understanding what you mean by undefined.